# 'Existing Entity' constraint

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm reading some data from an excel file, and hydrating it into an object of class `A`. Now I have to make sure that one of the fields of the data corresponds to the Id of a specific Entity. i.e:

```
class A{
     protected $entityId;
}
```

I have to make sure that `$entityId` is an **existing id** of a specific entity (let's call it `Foo`). Now this can be achieved using the `choice` constraint, by supplying the `choices` option as all of the existing ids of `Foo`. However this will obviously cause a performance overhead. Is there a standard/better way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by 'id of a specific entity'? Do you mean property/attribute?

Comment: I would expect the DoctrineBridge UniqueEntity constraint would work.  Assuming that your Foos live in a database.

Comment: @cerad `Foo`s definitely do live in the database. However `A`s don't. I can't see how I can use the UniqueEntity Constraint for two reasons: 1. it only enforces uniqueness NOT existence 2. it validates the root object i.e: `A` which does not live in a database.

Comment: Might want to read up a bit on constraints and the validator.  It's possible that I don't understand your question.  You can apply a constraint to anything, not just a class.  And if the UniqueConstraint fails then it implies that the object exists.  You you can just copy the code and change it's name to ExistsConstraint.

Comment: The problem is the `UniqueEntityValidator` presumes that the object of validation IS the entity itself, and uses it to retrieve the Entity Manager and etc. . How ever in my case I only want to validate a scalar value which is a property of a non-entity class. In regards to creating a new Constraint, it can definitely be done using some copy-paste and modification, but the whole point was to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about what you are doing, since you seem to talk about Excel parsing, but at the same time you mention `choices`, which in my opinion relate to Forms.

IMO you should handle directly the relationship to your entity, instead of only its id. Most of the time it is always better to have directly the related entity as attribute of your class A than only the id, and Symfony manipulates such behaviours pretty well.

Then just have your Excel parser do something like this:

```
$relatedEntity = $this->relatedEntityRepository->find($entityId);
if (!$relatedEntity) {
    throw new \Exception();
}
$entity->setRelatedEntity($relatedEntity);
```

After doing this, since you were talking about Forms, you can then use an `EntityType` field which will automatically perform the request in database. Use `query_builder` if you need to filter the results.